# How to add space between thousands in Rmarkdown?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

Good morning,

I am writing a document in Rmarkdown and I would like to format all the output tables so that I can have "10 000" rather than "10000" in my HTML rendering.

I work with the kableExtra package mainly. Do you know if there is a special function to do this ?

I tried this :

`kable(tableau_ST_CST, big.mark = " ") %>%  kable_styling(full_width = F)`

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`prettyNum`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/formatC):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)

tibble(nums = 10000:10010) %>% 
  mutate(nums = prettyNum(nums, big.mark = " ")) %>%
  kable()
|nums   |
|:------|
|10 000 |
|10 001 |
|10 002 |
|10 003 |
|10 004 |
|10 005 |
|10 006 |
|10 007 |
|10 008 |
|10 009 |
|10 010 |
```

Other options include `formatC`, `format` (both have the same format), or simply using regex (`str_replace_all("100000", pattern = "(\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+$)", "\\1 ")`).

Comment: it is not possible to apply a function to the whole of a table and not only to a column?

Comment: @Zaggamim you could apply it to every column with `mutate(across(everything(), ~ prettyNum(., big.mark = " ")))`